# Converting from netCDF to GeoTiff using gdal_translate

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

```
gdal_translate netcdf_file.nc output.tif
```

I'm trying to generate a GeoTiff using this command, and it works... kind of. The output tif image is just black and white, and I'd like actual colors on the output image. When I do a "gdalinfo" on the netCDF file, it says there is only 1 band, and that the "ColorInterp" is "Undefined."

Comment: There are no colors in 1 band image before you apply a color table into it.

Comment: So my next step should be finding out how to write multiple bands?

Comment: No, because you have only one band in your source data. Learn how to show your only band as pseudo-color by applying color table/palette. That depends on your viewer. Here is a tutorial for QGIS https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_styling_and_analysis.html.